# Database: Count rows in a table

Tags: php, sql

How to count rows in a table, if it's equals to one(1) record the data can't be deleted.

I tried something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) === 1){
   echo "Delete not allowed.";
} else {
   DELETE query here
}
```

Please help.

Comment: `count(*)` always returns one row, which contains the count.  You should look at the value being return, not the number of rows.

Comment: you can check this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php and while you are at it you can read the big warning at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable", $link); // Change query to this
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query); // Count rows

if ($num_rows === 1){ 
  echo "Delete not allowed.";
} else {
 // DELETE query here
}

?>
```

Check the documentation: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

You may change your query to

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
```

and the code will do.

You may change your query to

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as rows FROM mytable");
```

and look into the value of "rows", this will be the best and faster one.